# Tailwind sticky horizontally in grid

Tags: reactjs, scroll, grid, tailwind-css, sticky

I'm really struggling with working out how to make each element of the grid sticky on horizontal scroll. I've tried so many combinations but the {date} is never sticky. I've tried adding `overflow-x-scroll` to the parent, and changing `items-baseline` with `items-stretch` on both parent and child components. No matter what, the date is never sticky.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

```
<div
  className="items-baseline grid h-5 grid-cols-[repeat(240,32px)] text-neutral-600 overflow-x-auto"
>
  {[...Array(24)].map((_, i) => (
    <div
      key=key
      className="sticky top-0 whitespace-nowrap text-xs pt-2 dark:text-neutral-30"
      style={{
        gridColumn: i === 0 ? 1 : (24 * i * 2) + 1,
      }}
    >
      {date}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `top-0` to `left-0`.

Sticky elements are "positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor . . . based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left" - [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky). Because the scrolling is happening horizontally, we need to tell each child to stick when it is 0 (or however many) pixels away from the left (or right) side. You would only see the effects of `top-0` if there was some vertical scrolling.

Here is a [working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZI0Xwo9orZ) in a Tailwind Playground.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I actually ended up finding out about left-0 before and then I tried out your solution, and for some reason it's still not working. I also have a sticky at the top level for vertical scroll but I don't think it's affecting the horizontal scroll.

Here's the full code snippet:

```html
<div className="sticky top-0 z-30">
    <div className="grid h-5 grid-cols-[repeat(240,32px)] items-baseline overflow-x-auto text-neutral-600">
        {[...Array(24)].map((_, i) => (
        <div className="sticky left-0 whitespace-nowrap pl-1.5 pt-1 align-text-bottom text-xs dark:text-neutral-300" style={{ gridColumn: i===0 ? 1 : (24 * i * 2) + 1, }}>
            {date}
            <div className="absolute bottom-0.75 left-0 h-2/3 w-0.5 bg-neutral-300" />
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    <div className="grid h-5 grid-cols-[repeat(120,64px)]">
        {[...Array(7)].map((_, i) => (
        <div className="whitespace-nowrap py-1 text-xs dark:text-neutral-30" style={{ gridRow: 1, }}>
            {days}
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
</div>
```